# Is there a way to read command-line local mail in OS X's Mail application, or another OS X GUI?

Tags: macos, email

When I open Terminal it periodically tells me 'You have new mail.', some of which comes from testing web applications that I am running on localhost, which try to send it.

I find the command line mail application impossible to use.

Is there a way to read this mailbox from the OS X Mail application?

Comment: Similar question (although not limited to OS X): http://serverfault.com/questions/126182/front-end-to-linux-std-mailbox-for-development-purposes

Answer (score 1):

There was an [article](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=2004111223552833) on macosxhints.com that touched on this subject. Seems like what you're looking for is in there. The other option, if you just want to read the email/delete the email messages and don't really need them to be backed up you can read the /var/mail/$USERNAME file. That file is where those mails are being stored (it's a single text file). If you delete the file you'll stop seeing those alerts showing up in the Terminal.

Comment: This is a very dirty hack. And why must all the old mails be deleted?

Also: If the mbox is deleted the alerts will stop showing - until a new one arrives.

What about adding an mail alias?

Comment: The comments on the thread I linked suggests enabling postfix and setting up an alias to direct those emails to another external address. A symlink won't work because Mail.app actually deletes and recreates the mbox file during it's operation (at least according to some stuff I've read).

Comment: Hmmm, configuring an MTA can be a little bit dangerous -> open relay. And i think it's overkill for a developer's machine.

Comment: I've just tried the macosxhints article.

I'm not sure it's still up to date for 10.6, as Mail.app doesn't seem to be storing its messages in a mbox file: inside the newly-created FOLDERNAME.mbox folder I have a Messages folder, and in that a file with an .emlx extension which seems to be the message I copied over in the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

If the output is coming from cron jobs, try putting

```
MAILTO=address@example.com
```

in the crontab before the lines that interest you